# Get object id on drop with fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using the fullCalendar plugin to show a calendar with the different events and elements in. Some of then are draggable and therefore possible to alter the date etc. which I need to update in the database as well. But I'm getting stuck because I can't seem to find a way to get that id of the object that is being moved.

I have the code that takes the data out of DB and renders it in the calendar like this:

```
$scope.temp = [];
$scope.academy = [];
$http.get(api.getUrl('academy', user.id)).success(function (response) {
    $scope.temp = response;
    for (var j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
        $scope.academy.push({
            id: $scope.temp[j].id,
            title: $scope.temp[j].name,
            start: new Date($scope.temp[j].date).getTime(),
            className: 'bg-info bg',
            editable: true,
            location: $scope.temp[j].location,
            info: $scope.temp[j].description
        })
        if($scope.academy[j].start < $scope.time ) {
            $scope.academy[j].className= 'bg-success bg'
        }
        if(0 < $scope.academy[j].start-$scope.time && $scope.academy[j].start-$scope.time < 172800000) {
            $scope.academy[j].className= 'bg-danger bg'
            alert('Remember '+$scope.academy[j].title);
        }
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
            id: $scope.academy[j].id,
            title: $scope.academy[j].title,
            start:  $scope.academy[j].start,
            className: $scope.academy[j].className,
            editable: true,
            location: $scope.academy[j].location,
            info: $scope.academy[j].info
        }, true)
    }
});
```

I then have a onDrop function that is being activated whenever a drop happens. I can verify that with a simple alert().

```
/* alert on Drop */
$scope.alertOnDrop = function(){
    alert($('.calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'));
};
```

This obviously returns an alert with all the objects on the calendar, and if I add a specific id I get that specific object as [object Object]. But I need to get the object and id of whatever object is being dropped on the calendar and I could really use some inputs on how I can achieve that?

Comment: What does `$scope.alertOnDrop = function(e){console.log(e)};` give you in your console?

Comment: Guessing again but the id may be `e.id`, or if it returns a jQuery object `e.attr('id')`. Which is is?

Comment: Great. Just needed to send the object as parameter. I can work on from here. I don't know how this answers work in points or so. But if it matters you can write an answer and I will select it.

Comment: e.id returns the id of the object, so I can use it from there.

Comment: ok. posted as an answer so the question can have closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alertOnDrop gives you the element as the first argument of your anon function.

```
$scope.alertOnDrop = function(e){
    alert(e.id);
};
```